# Using react.js along side standard HTML

Tags: reactjs

I don't know if I'm overly obtuse on this or if I'm missing a key concept, but even though I think I "get" react.js as a framework, I have small disconnect when it comes to rendering.

Every example I've ever seen looks something like this:

```
var myComponent = React.createClass({
    // ...
});

React.render(<myComponent/>, 'containerID');
```

The call to render the component is bundled with the example component itself. OK, simple enough for demo purposes, but what if I have a site that uses other technologies to render, say, a list of items and I want to incorporate React.js to render some buttons for each item. My HTML might look like:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Item Name</span><img src="itemImage.jpg"/></li>
    <li><span>Item Name</span><img src="itemImage.jpg"/></li>
    <li><span>Item Name</span><img src="itemImage.jpg"/></li>
    <li><span>Item Name</span><img src="itemImage.jpg"/></li>
</ul>
```

Let's then say I make a react component in a separate .jsx file which I have transpiled / included in my app.js file somewhere along the way:

```
var LikeButton = React.createClass({ /* ... */ });
```

From the code that renders the list items, how do I add the LikeButton component for each `<li>`? What code can I insert here:

```
<li>
    <span>Item Name</span>
    <img src="itemImage.jpg"/>
    <whatgoeshere???>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, React.js works beautifully on Single Page Applications. That said, your item list(`<ul>...</ul>`) should be another React Component, let's call it ItemList, so you can make the Like Component a Mixin and then include the mixin in any other component (ItemList) you want. Then you only need to attach the ItemList component into the HTML.

IF the item list is already a React Component all you need to do is to use the jsx notation in each item like this:

```
<li>
  <span>Item Name</span>
  <img src="itemImage.jpg"/>
  <LikeButton/>
</li>
```

**EDIT**

Based on OP comment:

So, if the `<ul>` is plain HTML, you definitely cannot use the JSX syntax to add the like button or anything similar to what you would do in Angular.
I still think that the best approach is to have the item list extracted into another component but if you want to stick to it the only, ugly, way I can imagine is to have another html tag, let's say a div, inside each div and then inject the React component when the DOM is loaded, something like

```
<li>
  <span>Item Name</span>
  <img src="itemImage.jpg"/>
  <div class="likeAnchor"></div>
</li>

<script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(<LikeButton/>, document.getElementByClass('likeAnchor'));
</script>
```

Probably iterating over all the .likeAnchor elements.

Comment: Where the react component chain begins is not the issue. The issue is how to arbitrarily inject a react component into otherwise plain old HTML. I'm not working in the single page app use case here.

Comment: After thinking about it some, I was heading down the path mentioned in your edit. I think that React should probably add a auto-renderer for inline elements the way Angular handles directives e.g. (`<ul><li><likeButton/></li></ul>`)